# Instert data when you receive a push notification from GCM and your app was not runing

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I receive correctly a notification from *GCM* but I want insert the message in a local (sqlite) database.

If I receive the notification when my app is not running, it doesn't insert the message but if my application was running then it does.

```cs
void SendNotification (string message)
{
    var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
    intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

    var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder (this)
        .SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.icstatbutton_click)
        .SetContentTitle ("GCM Message")
        .SetContentText ("U heeft een nieuwe vragenlijst.")
        .SetAutoCancel (true)
        .SetContentIntent (pendingIntent);

    var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
    notificationManager.Notify (0, notificationBuilder.Build());

    try
    {
        DataAccess.InsertDownload (message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Can I access sqlite database when my application is not running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `DataAccess.InsertDownload()` method in your shared code? If so, that is the same thing I ran into.

Probably not the best way to solve it but what I did was to save the JSON string into Android's `SharedPreferences` if the app is in fact closed. Then the app is loaded again, within `MainActivity` and after loading the shared project, I attempt to read out any SharedPreferences and save them to the DB.

Below is some code showing this. [Here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Settings/Refractored.Xam.Settings.Android/Settings.cs) is a link to `SettingsImplementation`.

```
public async Task SaveNotifToDb(Notification notification) {
    try {
        DataAccess.InsertDownload (message); 
    } catch(System.InvalidOperationException) { //InvalidOperationException is the exception given when your shared code is not yet loaded, meaning the app is closed, so now lets save to Preferences
        System.Console.WriteLine("\nIn APP.Droid.Helpers.GcmService.SaveNotificationAsync() - InvalidOperationException, the app is probably closed. Saving to Shared Preferences\n");

        string notificationJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notification);

        string emptyCheck = SettingsImplementation.GetValueOrDefault<string>(DroidConstants.NotificationSettingKeyPart + "0", DroidConstants.NotificationSettingDefault);

        if(emptyCheck.Length > 0) {

            int index = 0;

            while(emptyCheck.Length > 0) {
                emptyCheck = SettingsImplementation.GetValueOrDefault<string>(DroidConstants.NotificationSettingKeyPart + index.ToString(), DroidConstants.NotificationSettingDefault);
                index ++;
            }

            SettingsImplementation.AddOrUpdateValue<string>(DroidConstants.NotificationSettingKeyPart + (index - 1).ToString(), notificationJson);
        } else { SettingsImplementation.AddOrUpdateValue<string>(DroidConstants.NotificationSettingKeyPart + "0", notificationJson); }

        return notification;
    }
}
```

Now when the app is started, we wait for the shared code to load and then try to read all the notification JSON back out.

MainActivity.OnCreate():

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

string notificationJson = SettingsImplementation.GetValueOrDefault(DroidConstants.NotificationSettingKeyPart + "0", DroidConstants.NotificationSettingDefault); //Check to see if we have a saved notification

    if(notificationJson.Length > 0) {

        int index = 0;

        while(notificationJson.Length > 0) { //Keep trying until no more notifications can be gatherd
            notificationJson = SettingsImplementation.GetValueOrDefault(DroidConstants.NotificationSettingKeyPart + index, DroidConstants.NotificationSettingDefault);

            if(notificationJson.Length > 0) {

                Data.Models.RemoteNotification notification = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data.Models.RemoteNotification>(notificationJson);

                if(notification != null) {

                    try {
                        await App.RemoteNotificationRepo.InsertAsync(notification);
                    } catch(System.Exception e) {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("\nIn APP.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate() - Exception attempting to create new in app notification\n{0}\n", e);
                    }
                }

                 SettingsImplementation.Remove(DroidConstants.NotificationSettingKeyPart + index.ToString());

                 index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can access Sqlite when application is not running. In your Activity's OnCreate you can check for new messages and update accordingly.